# .htaccess rerouting on AngularJS Project

Tags: angular, angularjs, .htaccess, angular-routing

I am trying to create a .htaccess file to handle routing for my Angular Web that were deployed on a hosting provider. The current .htaccess file is like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```

but when I tested it, there is a problem when I am trying a non-existing route. if the route is not exist, it should redirect to the landing page. but when trying to access a route that not exist, it just show a blank page. But, when I refresh the page, it does redirect to the page that i have set.

Can someone give me advice on how should I do the routing for the htaccess or angular routing for handling non-existing route?